# What's the difference between "Edit Links" and "Update Links" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have several large, complex Excel files with lots of embedded graphs that I have added to over time. When I open the files, I get a window with options to edit, update, or ignore links. The highlighted option is "Edit Links". If I click on it, I get a window with options to change source or break links. The highlighted option is "Change Source".

What are the differences between these options, and what would be the best choices?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a spreadsheet with cells that point to external files, you need a way to maintain those pointers in different ways for different purposes.  The external files can move, be renamed, have their contents changed, etc., or the spreadsheet could be copied to another computer.  You might do that to transfer the spreadsheet or to work on it somewhere else, in which case you might temporarily not need the linked files, or if you copy those files also, they would not be in the same location that the spreadsheet points to.  Excel gives you the ability to adjust for these kinds of changes.

Say you are just working on the spreadsheet somewhere else and the current state of the linked content isn't critical to that, and you plan to return the spreadsheet to its original location.  You don't want to change anything about the links, so you could choose to **ignore** them.  Another situation where you might want to ignore them is if you are debugging your spreadsheet.  That might be easier to do if everything remains the same as the last session except for the things you explicitly want to change for diagnostic purposes.

If you are transferring the spreadsheet plus the linked files to another computer, the linked files won't be where the links point on the original computer.  In that case you would **edit** the links so that they make sense in the new location.  **Change source** lets you point the links to the new location of the external files.  You could also use that if you need to move or rename the external files on the original computer.

In some cases, you might no longer need an active link to work with an external file that will be changing; you just want the spreadsheet to use what was the last state of the external file.  Examples of this situation would be using external files to produce various values needed to develop and test your spreadsheet, but not for the finished work, or wanting a simplified demo file that doesn't need to work with varying values in external files.  You can **break** the link, in which case the spreadsheet won't go looking for that file to update the referenced values.

If the external files might have changed contents since the last time you opened the spreadsheet, **update** links will refresh the values that are linked to those files.  It is an option because you might not always want to do that (for example, if you are debugging the spreadsheet).

Comment: Very concise explanation.